# Оптимальные MySQL запросы

Tags: база-данных, оптимизация, mysql

Всем привет. Решил Оптимизировать хоть немного запросы к базе MySQL.Я плохо в этом разбираюсь, поэтому решил спросить знающих людей:

1. Что лучше: Считать количество строк при каждом запросе, (при этом используя кеширование)или же хранить в базе уже число строк и просто выводить число из базы (Но мне кажется, что это не удобно, так как нужно будет при каждом изменение строк в базе нужно пересчитывать число заново. Или же все таки это лучше)?
2. Около 10 запросов с разных таблиц на главной странице, где большое число пользователей сайта просматривает эту страницу - это не сильно много? (P.S. Я правда не знаю, но мне кажется, при правильном кеширование должна нагрузка минимальная быть, а без нее?).
3. Сильно ли грузят изображения, опять же на главной странице сайта, где больше всего просмотров, если каждое изображение около 1 мб и ниже? Или же лучше ухудшать качество изображений?

*За ранее спасибо. Готов выслушать любые предложения.*

Comment: Приводите примеры кода!

>>>> Считать количество строк при каждом запросе

Конкретно операция

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table

В mysql - "бесплатна"

Comment: Я использую библиотеку Active Record Class, запрос получается самым простым: 

$this->db->where('second', $id);
$this->db->from('description');
$data['count'] = $this->db->count_all_results();

Comment: Что обозначает "бесплатна"? То есть быстрее всего выполняется? и не почти не ест ресурсов? =)

Comment: Это значит что у MySQL это число есть - и его достаточно прочитать и выдать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можете легко сделать своему сайту нагрузочное тестирование с помощью JMETER. его можно использовать как прокси для того чтоб записать все запросы которые отсылаются к серверу. а потом выполнить их. есть разные элементы для отображения статистики тестирования.

статистику он выбивает по запросам. поэтому в конце тестирования сразу будет видно у каких запросов нестабильное или самое большое время отдачи.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.

Answer (score 1):

1. лучше наверное эту переменную куда-то сохранять, закешировать, вставить в сессию. т.е. один раз её взять и отдать, а когда нужно изменить это значение, ну смотря как часто оно должно обновляться, обновить кеш для этой переменной.
2. Смотря какие запросы. Закешировать можно многое, главное знать и понимать насколько нужна актуальность данных на странице.
3. Конечно же сильно, 1 метр фотки - это много. С чем связаны такие траты?

И вопрос связан не только с MySql как я вижу.

Comment: Спасибо за советы. =) Да, за одно спросил и про вес изображений. =) Все же сколько должен быть вес изображения примерно для оптимального соотношения. скорости и качества?

Comment: ну я бы сказал так, взять фотошоп, взять фотку, уменьшить ей до нужного размера и сохранить в нужном формате, поиграть с настройками, выискать нужный размер. ну а потом, если на сайте используется php конвертация фоток, то и там попробовать разные варианты, и принять нужный.

Comment: К сожалению, этот способ не применим, так как фотографии загружаются динамически, их загружают пользователи и php уже сам работает с изображениями, обрезает, уменьшает и т.д.